# PasswordReset with WebSecurity in WebMatrix not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

Possible duplicate
[Webmatrix WebSecurity not authenticating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481119/webmatrix-websecurity-not-authenticating)

This is my `PasswordReset.cshtml` page :

```
@{
Layout="Layout.cshtml";
var uID = "";
var newPass = "";
var confirmPass = "";
var token = "";
if(IsPost){
uID = Request.Form["userID"];
newPass = Request.Form["newPassword"];
confirmPass=Request.Form["confirmPassword"];
token=WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(uID, 5);
WebSecurity.ResetPassword(token, newPass);
}else{
      Response.Redirect("Default");
      }
}
```

Now, the error message goes like this :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'userID' does not exist in the current context
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 10: newPass = Request.Form["newPassword"];

Line 11: confirmPass = Request.Form["confirmPassword"];

Line 12: token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(userID, 5);
 
Line 13: WebSecurity.ResetPassword(token, newPass);
```

I think the code is correct, but I can't figure out the cause of the error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That variable doesn't exist in the context above.  You're storing your user Id from Request.Form in `uId`, so did you mean:

```
WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(uID, 5);
```

Comment: yeah, sorry. my bad. I meant that.

Comment: But that still redirects me to the Default page.
I can't see the rest of my HTML form, where the user enters the new password.